# Specify type of generic typed component without using "export let prop"

Tags: typescript, components, svelte

I have a generic Modal component. This component gives the programmer a nice interface to write his modal in. For example, you can open an arbitrary form to insert values into. When the form is completed and confirmed, the written data can be passed through the `modal.success(...)` function. The function `modal.success(...)` creates a dispatch and passes on the result to `<Modal on:success={event => {...}}`.

My problem is that the function `modal.success(...)` is not connected to `<Modal on:success={event => {...}}`. It would be awesome if `<Modal>` could infer the type from `modal.success(form_data)`, but this should of course not work as `modal.success` can be called in multiple places. One solution i would like and could imagine, is to be able to simply specify the type by writing something like `<Modal<MyFormType>>` (This is Typescript notation, but something alike for HTML).

One bad solution is to create a dummy prop in `<Modal>` to infer the type from. I can the create a dummy variable of type `MyFormType` (or just use `form_data`) and use this variable to pass the type to `<Modal>`. But i dont like this solution.

I notice, that instead of using the `event` from `on:success` to retrieve the form data, i could simply just use the `form_data` variable, but i dont like the idea of defining a variable in the "global" scope within this page for every modal there might be. Therefore i hope to find a good way to define a variable containing the form data within the `<Modal> <Modal/>` scope, and i believe part of that solution is to be able to pass the result through `modal.success()` to `on:success(event => {...})`.

+page.svelte:

```
<script>
    let form_data: MyFormType = { ... } 
<script/>

<Modal on:success={event => {...}}> 

    <button slot="button" let:modal on:click={() => modal.show()}> Show Modal </button>

    <article slot="modal" let:modal>

        <header>
            Insert data into some custom form.
        </header>
    
        <MyCustomForm bind:form_data/>
    
        <footer>
            <a href="#cancel" role="button"
            on:click={() => modal.cancel()}> Cancel </a>
    
            <a href="#confirm" role="button"
            on:click={() => modal.success(form_data)}> Confirm </a>
        </footer>

    </article>
</Modal>
```

CustomModal.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts" strictEvents generics="T">
    import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

    // I want this dispatch type to be connected to the function "success(result: T)".
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher<{success: T}>()

    let dialog_element: HTMLDialogElement;
    let modal_is_shown = false;

    function show() {
        dialog_element.showModal()
    }

    function cancel() {
        dialog_element.close()
    }

    function success(result: T) {
        dialog_element.close()
        dispatch("success", result)
    }

</script>


<slot modal={{ show }} name="button"/>

<dialog bind:this={dialog_element}>
    <slot modal={{ cancel, success }} name="modal"/>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating this.

There is no compelling reason to go through `modal.success` in the first place, it just closes the modal and spits the data back out. Might as well only close the modal manually (remove `success` and turn `cancel` into `close`) and maybe call a function directly instead. The data is already locally available, so there is no reason to go through an event to retrieve it.

It would be different if the buttons were to be created by the `Modal` itself, so you could only know what was clicked from the outside via events, but since the buttons are created in the component that also adds the Modal, you can just directly do the "correct thing" in the respective button `click` events.

Comment: That is true, so adding the function to the button itself can be greatly justified in this scenario. But if we look aside from this specific example, is it possible to specify the generic type of a component without using "export let"? Or is it idiomatically never necessary to define the type without "export let", and i would never come across to actually need this option/feature?

Comment: You *generally* should not need it, at least I have not encountered any such issues before.

Comment: Okay, then i do your suggestion, and leave this discussion be, thank you!